# Checking a solution of PDE

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions, complex

I'm having trouble verifying solutions for complex PDEs including **conjugate** and **absolute value**.

**For Example:**
I have a complex PDE:
[image]
where superscript * denotes conjugate of the unknown function  `ψ[x, t]`.

**Candidate solution:**

```
a = 1/2 (8 β - b Subscript[A, 1]^2)

 ψ[x_, t_] :=E^(I (-k x + θ + 
  1/2 t (-8 k^2 β - 2 γ + 2 b Subscript[A, 1]^2 + 
     b k^2 Subscript[A, 1]^2))) Subscript[A, 1] Tanh[x + k t (8 β - b Subscript[A, 1]^2)];
```

I want to check that the candidate solution satisfies the PDE or not:

```
    (*Checking the solution*)
            FullSimplify[
             I*D[ψ[x, t], t] + a*D[ψ[x, t], {x, 2}] + 
               b*ComplexExpand@(Abs[ψ[x, t]]^2)*ψ[x, t] -  β/(
                ComplexExpand@(Abs[ψ[x, t]]^2)* 
                 ComplexExpand@
                  Conjugate[ψ[x, t]] )*(2*Abs[ψ[x, t]]^2*
                   D[ComplexExpand@(Abs[ψ[x, t]]^2), {x, 2}] - (D[
                    ComplexExpand@(Abs[ψ[x, t]]^2), x])^2) - γ*ψ[
                 x, t] == 0 ]
```

Comment: better not use Subscript variables. This asks for trouble. To verify solution, write the solution as  `sol= Psi->Function[{x,t},.... solution you want to check...]` then do `pde/.sol` and hope you get `True`. Might have to simplify and wait long time.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I tried to your answer: `sol = \[Psi] -> Function[{x, t}, 
   E^(I (-kx + \[Theta] +1/2 t (-8 k^2 \[Beta] - 2 \[Gamma] + 2 b Subscript[A, 1]^2 + b k^2 Subscript[A, 1]^2))) Subscript[A, 1] Tanh[ x + k t (8 \[Beta] - b Subscript[A, 1]^2)]] `  and also...

Comment: `a = 1/2 (8 \[Beta] - b Subscript[A, 1]^2) 
PDE = I*D[\[Psi][x, t], t] + a*D[\[Psi][x, t], {x, 2}] + 
   b*ComplexExpand@(Abs[\[Psi][x, t]]^2)*\[Psi][x, 
     t] - \[Beta]/(ComplexExpand@(Abs[\[Psi][x, t]]^2)*
       ComplexExpand@Conjugate[\[Psi][x, t]])*(2*Abs[\[Psi][x, t]]^2*
       D[ComplexExpand@(Abs[\[Psi][x, t]]^2), {x, 2}] - (D[
         ComplexExpand@(Abs[\[Psi][x, t]]^2), 
         x])^2) - \[Gamma]*\[Psi][x, t] == 0
PDE /. sol` But I didn't get `True`or `False`

Answer (score 2):

You've missed one `ComplexExpand` for `Abs[ψ[x, t]]^2`. Since there're so many `ComplexExpand[Abs[ψ[x, t]]^2]` and `ψ[x, t]` in your code, why not simplifying the code with `With`?:

```
With[{ψ = ψ[x, t]}, 
 With[{abs = ComplexExpand[Abs[ψ]^2]}, 
  I D[ψ, t] + a D[ψ, {x, 2}] + 
    b abs ψ - (β (2 abs D[abs, {x, 2}] - (D[abs, x])^2))/(abs ComplexExpand[
        Conjugate[ψ]]) - γ ψ // Simplify]]
(* 0 *)
```