# Unable to solve Delay PDEs Error in Boussinesq Approximation

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, heat-equation, fluid-dynamics, axisymmetry

I'm trying to solve the set of equations below describing the flow of a pot of water being heated slightly. The equations are 2D axisymmetric in nature.

```
x0 = 1;
y0 = 1;
\[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {x0, y0}];
\[Mu]water = 8.9*10^-4;
\[Alpha]water = 2.1* 10^-4;
kwater = 0.6;
Cwater = 4184;
\[Rho]water = 1000;
g = 9.78;

eqn1=D[vr[r,z,t],t]+vz[r,z,t]*D[vr[r,z,t],z]+vr[r,z,t]*D[vr[r,z,t],r]+D[p[r,z,t],r]/\[Rho]water-\[Mu]water (D[vr[r,z,t],z,z]+(D[r*D[vr[r,z,t],r],r]/r)-vr[r,z,t]/r^2)/\[Rho]water==0;
eqn2=D[vz[r,z,t],t]+vz[r,z,t]*D[vz[r,z,t],z]+vr[r,z,t]*D[vz[r,z,t],r]+D[p[r,z,t],z]/\[Rho]water-\[Mu]water (D[vz[r,z,t],z,z]+(D[r*D[vz[r,z,t],r],r]/r))/\[Rho]water==g \[Alpha]water T[x, y, t];
eqn3=D[vz[r,z,t],z]+D[r vr[r,z,t],r]/r==0;
eqn4=D[T[r,z,t],t]-kwater ((D[r*D[T[r,z,t],r],r]/r)+D[T[r,z,t],z,z])/(\[Rho]water Cwater)+vz[r,z,t] D[T[r,z,t],z]+vr[r,z,t] D[T[r,z,t],r]==0;

wall = DirichletCondition[{vr[r, z, t] == 0, vz[r, z, t] == 0}, r == 1];
reference = DirichletCondition[p[r, z, t] == 0, r == 0 && z == 0];
temperatures = {DirichletCondition[T[r, z, t] == 1, r == 1]};
bcs = {wall, reference, temperatures};
ic = {vz[r, z, 0] == 0, vr[r, z, 0] == 0, p[r, z, 0] == 0, T[r, z, 0] == 0};

Monitor[AbsoluteTiming[{xVel, yVel, pressure, temperature} = NDSolveValue[{eqn1, eqn2, eqn3,eqn4, bcs, ic}, {vz, vr, p, T}, {r, z} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], {t, 0, 200},Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement","MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0000625}, "InterpolationOrder" -> {vz -> 2, vr -> 2, p -> 1, T -> 2}}}}, EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])];],currentTime]
```

After running the code, I get the error that Delay PDEs are not supported by mathematica. When I search online, most of the methods to fix this error is to use the method of lines which I have used in NDSolve, but still have not been able to fix this. Anyone knows what's wrong?

Comment: @user21 I think this is another parsing bug?

Comment: @xzczd I think the firs thing to do is to put it in inactive form.

Comment: @user21 is it possible to put it into inactive form? I don’t know if I can specify grad and div in terms of cylindrical coordinates while using the axisymmetric condition. Also out of curiosity what’s the difference between the inactive and active forms when it comes to solving?

Comment: Have a look at the [DiffusionPDETerm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiffusionPDETerm.html) (et al) ref pages, that have a "RegionSymmetry" -> "Axisymmetric" parameter. I have not tried this myself, you might need to fiddle a little with the equation too. Concerning the the inactive form, this specifies what the meaning of  NeumannValue is, but also a few other things....

Comment: ...See [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html#1585211872) and [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html#1216827418), Not quite what you are looking for but perhaps also useful is the [axisymmetric Tubular Reactor](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/Multiphysics/ModelCollection/TubularReactor.html) example.

Comment: Also, I'd try to do an axisymmetric fluid flow problem first and then couple the already available axisymmetric [HeatTransferPDEComponent](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeatTransferPDEComponent.html). Start simple!

Comment: Also see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166310/solving-navier-stokes-equations-for-a-steady-state-compressible-viscous-flow-in) question and also [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225711/reveal-the-formal-pde-of-finiteelement)

Comment: ……There's a `T[x, y, t]` in your code, it should be `T[r, z, t]`. I suggest using `With` to simplify your code as shown in e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/249782/1871 to avoid mistake like this.

Comment: Oh my god I can't believe I didn't see this... thanks for the tip. When I fix the arguments of T I get the error NDSolve: Zero pivot was detected during the numerical factorization or there was a problem in the iterative refinement process. It is possible that the matrix is ill-conditioned or singular. l'll try using user21's suggestions to fix this

Comment: I've played around with the code a little... I've ran into another issue and have made a seperate post about it https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282502/ndsolve-stops-solving-past-a-certain-time